# Instantiating C++ Class in on Mac XCode

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get some old code running on a Mac. The code uses template classes

I have a .h file containing the template class definitions.
I have a .cpp file containing the template members definitions.

Then I have a .cpp file for each type.

```
#include "template.h"
#include "template.cpp"

MyClass<whatevertype>  dummyobject ;
```

That had worked with the other compilers I had uses a number of years ago. However, XCode gives a linker error for missing class definitions.

I get warnings on the template.cpp file:

1. I originally had the template member functions qualified with EXPORT. That gave a compiler warning (ignored).
2. Following some of the answers on this board, I changed EXPORT to INLINE. That gave the warning it is being ignored.
3. I have non-template functions referenced by the template member functions in the template.cpp file. I get a warning saying they are not referenced and being ignored (indicating the template class is not being instantiated).

I was wondering what the procedure I need to use in XCode on the max to get the template classes to instantiate.

Let me try to give the Readers' Digest version. This is the arrangement I had used previously on Windoze years ago to instantiate the template class years ago. It does not work on Mac. I get undefined errors for the members.

```
template.h
// Defines the template class. Highly simplified example shown.
template class MyClass<unsigned int SIZE>
{
public:
    void someMethod() ;
} ;

template.cpp
// Defines the template class member functions. 

#include "template.h"
inline void doSomething ()
{
 // XCode gives warning that doSomething is not generated. Providing another
 // example that the class is not being instantiated.
}

{inline | export} void template MyClass<unsigned int SIZE>::someMethod ()
{
   for (unsigned int ii = 0 ; ii < SIZE ; ++ ii)
         doSomething () ;
}

myinstance.cpp
// Attempt to instantiate
#include "template.cpp"
MyClass<42> dummyObject ;
```

Comment: `EXPORT`? `INCLUDE`? None of that makes sense. Perhaps you would be better served if you provided a small example if something that doesn't work (but you think should work) so people could address what you're doing rather than trying to interpret a description.

Comment: I mistake on my part. I meant the export/inline qualifiers and put them in uppercase to make them stand out.

Comment: Using `#include` for anything other than headers is usually a code smell... Also, you aren't telling us what the errors/warnings are, or what `EXPORT` and `INLINE` are.

Comment: A code example speaks a thousand words....

Comment: A code example is a thousand words.